# Vagrant up after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10

I am trying to vagrant up after my recent upgrade to windows 10, and I get an error:

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *,int,int *)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Before the upgrade it worked fine, has anyone figured out how to fix this?

Comment: It appears Windows 10 isn't a supported host operating system yet: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#hostossupport. Have you tried reinstalling Virtualbox, however?

Comment: Yeah, just did. Now I get: `The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system.`

Comment: It appears you will need to wait for a new release of VirtualBox then... :/

Comment: It looks like the issues are resolved in the latest versions: Vagrant 1.7.4 and VirtualBox 5.0.2 does work.

Comment: Actually, VirtualBox's issue tracker is still littered with issues about `VBoxManage hostonlyif create`. I just checked and a fresh install of VirtualBox 5.1.2 on my Windows 10 machine produces the exact same errors as OP mentions. So no, it's still not (completely) fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got my Vagrant to finally work on Windows10:

- Uninstall both VirtualBox and Vagrant (backup the old vagrantmachines)
- Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.1-101902-Win.exe) and the latest Vagrant

Comment: Updating VirtualBox + Vagrant with the latest version (without uninstall) did the trick for me.

Comment: Right now, the latest version of VirtualBox is: 5.1.2 Build 108956, available for direct download here - http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.2/VirtualBox-5.1.2-108956-Win.exe

Answer (score 1):

There is a released fix for virtual box on https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040

For those using homestead a solution can be found on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` was removed once the upgrade to Windows 10 was completed. Removing, rebooting and installing VirtualBox resulted in the installation of the removed Ethernet adapters again and the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Another fix is to add `name: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"` after config.vm.network in your Vagrant file. In my case:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10", name: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
```

Vagrant, Virtual Box 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded today from Windows 7 Professional to Windows 10. 
When I was trying to boot a VM (Laravel Homestead) using vagrant it doesn't start.

I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant (without uninstall and reboot the machine) and then I reboot the machine. Once I did this the VM starts correctly.